# Saltstack formulas (starter)

Tags: saltstack

Is any saltstack formula 'skeleton' available so it can create a structure as described [here](https://salt-zh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/conventions/formulas.html)?

In chef you have `knife cookbook create` or in ansible `ansible-galaxy init`.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the [template-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/template-formula) from the [official SaltStack formulas](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas) repository.